# GridView: horizontal scroll does not work

Tags: android, gridview

I want to implement next:
 in each row of grid view some nomber of visible elements, to reach other elements we can use horizontal scroll. But:

Code 1:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvTimeTape"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="30"
    android:paddingLeft="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
</GridView>
```

Result (One row, all elements fit the screen):

[image]

Code 2:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvTimeTape"
    android:layout_width="5000dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:numColumns="30"
    android:paddingLeft="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
</GridView>
```

Result (elements not fit on the sreen and horizontall scroll not appears)

[image: result 2]

Does anybody knows in what trick?

Comment: I don't think that GridView can scrol horizontally. ListView either. They both extend AbsListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your GridView to HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but gridview does not work inside horizonalscrollview

Comment: Maybe for your task would be better use TableLayout?